# The Ruby way to group and count, refactor

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

I have a table that stores what users input into a search field. I wrote an action that displays the most popular searches and the number of times the search has been made. To do this I wrote the following sql query in the controller...

```
SELECT `query`,
       COUNT(`query`) AS `query_count`
FROM  `searches`
WHERE [foo things]
GROUP BY `query`
ORDER BY `query_count` DESC
```

... and pass that as a variable into a `Search.find_by_sql(query)`, save that as an instance variable, and iterate over the array with an each block and printing out `search['query_count']`. This does what exactly what I want, but I'd love to know how to do this in a Ruby way, because I know it's bad practice to just have sql queries in your controller. I know how to put `WHERE` conditions into named_scopes, but I don't know how to replicate the rest of the query in Ruby.

I'm using mysql, ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.15.

Answer (score 2):

Should be as easy as:

```
Search.select(:query, 'count(query) as query_count').where(foo things).group(:query).order('query_count DESC')
```